# el metodo me retorna 0

Tags: java

```
public static float porcentaje (String estado[], int edad[], int n) 
{       
   int contador = 0;

   for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
   {        
      if (estado[i].equalsIgnoreCase("casado") && (edad[i] == 20)) 
      {         
         contador++;
      }
   }

   return (contador / n) * 100;
}
```

Comment: Es probable que contador sea 0 porque no haya ninguna persona con casada y con 20 años. Por cierto, agrega una explicación aunque sea pequeña a tu pregunta. No podemos adivinar cuál es tu pregunta, qué falla o problema tienes.

Comment: cuando meto 2 personas una soltera y una casada en vez de darme  50% de personas casadas  me da 0 pero si en cambio meto dos personas casadas me da 100%

Comment: Hola Alexander, como te comentaba en mi respuesta, actualicé tu pregunta para formatear el codigo, agregar mas informacion basado en tu comentario y colocar la pregunta mas concreta, esto con el fin de ayudar a que la informacion sea mas clara para otras personas que se encuentren con un problema similar. Saludos!

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 1):

Lo mas posible en este caso es que se deba a que la división esta sucediendo con aritmética de números enteros `(contador/n)`.

Al ser ambas variables `contador` y `n` de tipo `int`, el calculo de la división se realizara en aritmética entera, es decir, nunca te va a devolver un número decimal que es lo que estas buscando.

Tienes varias formas de indicarle al compilador que deseas hacer la operación con números decimales, por ejemplo, una opción es hacer un `cast` a un tipo flotante:

```
return ((double) contador/n)*100;
```

En este caso, Java detecta que uno de los operandos de la división, en este caso `(double) contador` es de tipo flotante entonces va a efectuar la división con aritmética de punto flotante (y generará los decimales que estas buscando para calcular el porcentaje).

Alexander, voy a actualizar tu pregunta y agregar un comentario para aclarar porque, espero no sea problema.

Espero la informacion haya sido de ayuda!

Comment: muchisimas gracias me fue de gran ayuda soluciono mi problema

Comment: Si esta respuesta te ha ayudado a solucionar tu problema deberias aceptarla para mostrar tu agradecimiento al autor de la misma y para que la pregunta no quede pendiente para siempre. En este [enlace](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/428/263200) aprenderás a aceptar respuestas. Lectura recomendada para aprender el funcionamiento del sitio: [tour]